# Performance Measures

Tags: predictive-modeling, confusion-matrix

I run the following models..Decision tree, Logistic Regression,Naive Bayes, SVM and Random Forest ..I am given certain input features and  Respnse feature as whether a customer will buy the product or not in that context i am asking this question , i went through possibly all definitions available on internate but could not be able to properly figure out which measure i should consider as proper performance measure , so far as my models are concern Is there any proper meaning for the following concepts in data analysis.

Precision

Recall

F measure

I am looking for an easy explanation of these concepts with example?

Comment: Closing because many simple definitions are readily available on the internet. Without understanding why those are insufficient it's almost impossible to answer

Comment: I change my problem.....kindly make it

Answer (score 5):

Maybe not the answer you would like to hear, but I have to admit that I find wikipedia page on the topic definitively well done...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall